# How to optimize this SASS media query?

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass, media-queries

I have the id `#wants-to-meet` which at 1150px I wanted to change it's CSS.

Normally with media queries all I have to do is just target the id
 and sometimes I need to write something like `'parent-selector > targeted-selector'`

However my media query is getting crossed-out / negated for some reason:
[image]

And for some reason I **needed to go this deep** to get it to change:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1150px) {
            #li-affiliate-incoming-msg {
                #message_container {
                    #td-details {
                        #request_details {
                            #wants-to-meet {
                                margin-top: 5px;
                                margin-right: 0;
                                padding: 8px 20px 3px 20px;
                                color: blue;
                                background: red;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm using SASS and my `#wants-to-meet` id is nested 8 tabs deep, could this be the reason why?

Would you know why this is the case?

Comment: Note: For all selectors I'm trying to change in my media query I have to nest from all the way back to '#li-affiliate-incoming-msg'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This reeks of bad nesting. It's a good rule of thumb to only nest three or four levels deep. If you're using IDs in your markup, there's no reason to nest at all since IDs can only occur once.

Basically instead of saying `#wants-to-meet` to the browser, you're saying `#wants-to-meet` (browser says ok, got it) that's a child of `#request_details` (browser says ok, got it) that's a child of `#td-details` (browser says ok, got it) that's a child of `#message_container` (browser says ok, got it) that's a child of `#li-affiliate-incoming-msg` (browser says ok, got it).

It's redundant. Familiarize yourself with CSS specificity here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Sidenote: it's terrible practice to name a class or ID with an html element as you seem to have done with `#li-affiliate-incoming-msg`

Comment: Ah thanks! Yeah that makes sense... I guess I like to write CSS/SASS in a visually organized way. It makes sense to me that way, and also makes it quick to find the selectors I need. Hmm I'll re-organize my SASS to not get so crazy with nesting. And thanks for the link!

Comment: It's outside the scope of this question but you may want to research nested media queries within SASS. Could help you out a lot.

Comment: thanks I found this link http://designshack.net/articles/css/sass-and-media-queries-what-you-can-and-cant-do/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there are [more specific selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) therefore a `#wants-to-meet` is not enough.

A **dirty fix** would be:

```
#wants-to-meet {
    some-prop: value !important;
}
```

To override more specific matcher values. Nevertheless you should read through and understand all about [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to know which path suits you the best, and why.

Comment: Telling someone who clearly doesn't understand specificity to use !important is downright sinful.

Comment: Ah thanks for that! :) though now I understand what's going on thanks to @imjared I write my SASS this way because it helps me visually organize everything. I'll have to optimize it a bit more now :(

Comment: I am aware of that. Updated the answer with a recommendation. I just wanted to list it as a short (dangerous?) alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Where possible you should just use the id selector wherever you are styling that element - that should be specific enough as you can't use the same id multiple times.

```
#wants-to-meet {
```

However, you do need to make sure you refer to the element this way everywhere - as a more specific version of the selector will give you cascade-woes.

I believe the reason the style is crossed out is because the standards version of `border-radius` is supported - so the `-moz` version is overridden by the standards version.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS on line 1776 is [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the rules on line 1900; which is why line 1900's declarations are all crossed out.  Certainly that specificity is coming from the very deep Sass.